# use statement inside another class

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am going through a Laracast tutorial which suggest me to have the statement *`use DatabaseTransactions;`*  inside my test class definition, to allow the data changes in my test case will persists only for that case.
I have a test class,

```
    Class MyClassTest extends TestCase
    {

    // This use statement is responsible for 
    //all the data operations to persists only with in that test case
    use DatabaseTransactions;
     /**
     * @test
     */  
     public function my_test_function()
    {
     // My test case code. Which inserts/updates 
     //data and assert statement.
    }
    }
```

The `use DatabaseTransactions` works in a way that the data changes in the method persists only with in that. How that works exactly?

Comment: ...a little more context and code sample would help here...

Answer (score 0):

As went further, `DatabaseTransactions` is trait, which contains the method `beginDatabaseTransaction` with `@before` annotation.

- Having an `use DatabaseTransactions` within the test class lets the class have that method.
- Since the method `beginDatabaseTransaction` contains a `@before` annotation, it will be executed before every test case.
- The below is the method definition which begins a transaction and rolls back existing transaction before the test case finishes(it is still unclear why `@before` should be called before the test case finishes).

  @before

  public function beginDatabaseTransaction()
  {

  ```
  $this->app->make('db')->beginTransaction();

  $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
      $this->app->make('db')->rollBack();
  });
  ```

  }